# CSS transform-origin not working in safari as expected

Tags: css, ios, safari, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to rotate(spinning) the SVG about its center with `transform-origin: center`. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox and in Safari at 100% zoom. When I tried to zoom-out or zoom-in the page in Safari, SVG is not rotated about its center.

https://jsbin.com/duwezonate/1/edit?html,css,output You can check this link by accessing it from Chrome and Safari

Here's my code snippet:

```css
circle {
  stroke: currentColor;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: 1s infinite rotate-360;
}

@keyframes rotate-360 {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <circle fill="none" cx="25" cy="25" r="12" stroke-dasharray="50" stroke-dashoffset="10" />
</svg>
```

Comment: In Safari/IOS the thing doesn't seem to spin at all - perhaps because 360deg and 0deg are deemed to be equivalent. If you go to 359deg you get rotation. What OS/version of Safari are you getting some rotation on?

Comment: I'm using safari v16.4. The svg is spinning but not about its center.

Answer (score 0):

It is known issue since 2014 and following is ticket: [Bug Link](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=133150)